# How do I deal with the integration limits of the integrals that show up when showing that$Kx(t)=\int_0^tK(t,\tau)x(\tau)d\tau, x\in X$ is compact?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $X=C(I)$ with the sup norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, where $I=[0,1]$. Let $K$ be a Volterra integral operator:

$$Kx(t)=\int_0^tK(t,\tau)x(\tau)d\tau, x\in X$$

Show that K: $X\rightarrow X$,  is compact

I am having trouble with the $t$ variable present both in $K(t,\cdot)$ and in the integral integration limit. Most examples I've found are easier because they have $K(t,\tau)=1$ or the integral is from 0 to 1.

I have already shown that K is linear,

1)K is bounded:

$|Kf(t)|=|\int_0^tK(t,\tau)f(\tau)d\tau|\le \int_0^t|K(t,\tau)f(\tau)|d\tau \le \int_0^1|K(t,\tau)f(\tau)|d\tau \le\| f\|_{\infty}\int_0^1|K(t,\tau)|d\tau $

Since $K$ is continuous over a compact set, by Weierstrass theorem $\|K(\cdot, \cdot)\|\le M$, with $M$ some real number so  $|Kf(t)|=\| f(\tau)\|_{\infty}M $

Then  $\|Kf\|_\infty=\sup_t|Kf(t)|\le\| f\|_{\infty}M $  so K is bounded and $\|K\|\le M $

2)$K$ is compact

To show T is compact I have to use Ascoli-Arzelà theorem to the image of the unit ball with rispect to the sup norm: $K(B(0;1))$, so I need to verify the hypotheses of the theorem

$B=B(0;1)=\{f \in C[0,1], \|f\|_\infty <1\}$

i) K(B) is bounded because  $\|Kf\|_\infty=\sup_t|Kf(t)|\le\| f\|_{\infty}M \le M \forall f \in B$

ii) K(B) is equicontinuous:

From the uniform continuity of $K$ with respect to the first variable, I have that $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall t_1, t_2 \in [0,1]$, $|K(t_1,\cdot)-K(t_2, \cdot)|\le \varepsilon$...(*)

$|\int_0^tK(t,\tau)f(\tau)d\tau -\int_0^{t_0}K(t_0,\tau)f(\tau)d\tau|$

**I don't know how to bound this, if I use the triangle inequality I'd lose the minus sign and then I can't use (*). Can someone shed some light? Is the rest of the proof ok?**

**hint:** The book says that there is a discontinuity line at $\tau = t$ and that in the analogous easier proof with upper integration limit =1 that is given in the book, the continuity of K on the points $(t,\tau)$ for $t<\tau$ was not used.  I don't know what they mean or how to use this hint

**Edit** This is the proof they give in the book for the easier case. Somehow the hint is suggesting that either the proof is the same or there is a slight modification, but I can't figure it out

[image]

[image]

Comment: Idea: Triangle inequality after adding and subtracting something like $\int_0^t K(t_0,\tau)f(\tau)\, d\tau$.

Comment: @Jose27 I get two integrals $|\int_0^t (K(t,\cdot)-K(t_0,\cdot))f(\tau)d\tau+\int_{t_0}^t K(t_0,\cdot)f(\tau)d\tau| $ after grouping , the first one can be bounded  easily with $\varepsilon$ but the other one I don't know

Comment: Use that $K(\cdot, \cdot)$ and $f(\cdot)$ are both uniformly bounded (since $f\in B(0,1)$).

Comment: @Jose27 I already tried that, the problem is that bounding that integral with a constant that does not depend on $\varepsilon$ does not help. I would have something like "$<\varepsilon + C$" at the end

Comment: @J.C.VegaO I don't know if this will help, but you can write $$Kx(t) = \int_{0}^{1}I(\tau \leq t)K(t, \tau)x(\tau)\,d\tau.$$

Comment: Notice the limits of integration! You get a bound like $C|t_0-t|$, which is good if you want to get equicontinuity.